# What is System.Signature?

Tags: visual-studio, memory-leaks, windows-runtime, profiler

When running Visual Studio's memory profiler (Memory Usage Analysis) on my Windows Store app it shows me that there are many objects of type `System.Signature` (mscorlib.dll) on the heap.

I can't find `System.Signature` in the Object Browser, so I assume that it is some internal class only used and only usable by the Framework.
Does anyone have more information about this class?
When or why are `System.Signature` objects created and what are they used for internally?

According to the memory profiler, the number of `System.Signature` objects raises constantly while the app is used. This looks like a memory leak to me, but where do these objects come from or what creates these objects? To answer this question, I first need to know what `System.Signature` actually is.

[image: Memory usage analysis view in Visual Studio]

Comment: It is an internal helper class used by Reflection to store the details of a method.  That you are using Reflection is also visible by the count for RuntimeType.  Reflection info gets cached to make it cheap.  Why your program is using a lot of reflection is of course not obvious, the object counts certainly are not outrageous.  A profiler has a knack for showing details you should not be interested in.